# Using a SOAP WebService containing JSON Payload

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, soap

I am trying to write a WebApp that consumes SOAP web services that embeds JSON data, and have hit a challenge. I'd appreciate assistance on this. Thank you.

Below is the expected structure of the Web Service Request:

```
<logonrequest>
    {
    "userid":"username",
    "password":"password",
    "Timestamp":""
    }
</logonrequest>
```

Below is the structure of the expected Web Service Response:

```
<return>
    {
        "userid":"username",
        "displayName":"Firstname Lastname",
        "accountBalance":0.0,
        "statusCode":"0|SUCCESS",
        "statusDesc":"Logon Success",
        "sessionid":"12047CC560484D21BD328EC8F22814ED",
        "lastTransactionTime":"20131130234326"
    }
</return>
```

Below is my Code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.soap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {
                $.soap({
                    url: 'URL GOES HERE',
                    elementName: 'logonrequest',
                    appendMethodToURL: false,
                    soap12: false,
                    data: "{'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}",
                    // data: {
                    //     'logonrequest': "{'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}"
                    // },
                    beforeSend: function (SOAPRequest)  {
                        alert('Request: ' + SOAPRequest);
                    },
                    success: function (soapResponse) {
                        alert('0: success');
                    },
                    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
                        alert('1: failed');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>
        Calling Web Services with jQuery/AJAX
    </h3>
    Enter your name:
    <input id="txtName" type="text" />
    <input id="btnCallWebService" value="Call web service" type="button" />
    <div id="response" />
</body>
</html>
```

Using this:

```
 elementName: 'logonrequest',
 ...
 data: "{'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}"
```

I get

```
Error: Invalid XML: {'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}
```

Using this:

```
 elementName: 'logonrequest' OR method: 'logonrequest',
 ...
 data: {
     'logonrequest': "{'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}"
 }
```

The request fails, because the request actually created is:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <logonrequest>
            <logonrequest>
                {
                    'userid':'bernard',
                    'password':'password',
                    'Timestamp':''
                }
            </logonrequest>
        </logonrequest>
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

How can I have it send a request that looks exactly like the required sample request above to successfully hit the services? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could achieve what you want on the request side was to use this:

```
    <html>
 <head>
    <title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.soap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {
                $.soap({
                    url: 'URL GOES HERE',
                    appendMethodToURL: false,
                    soap12: false,
                    data: "<logonrequest>{'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}</logonrequest>",
                    // data: {
                    //     'logonrequest': "{'userid':'bernard','password':'password','Timestamp':''}"
                    // },
                    beforeSend: function (SOAPRequest)  {
                        alert('Request: ' + SOAPRequest);
                    },
                    success: function (soapResponse) {
                        console.log(soapResponse);
                        alert('0: success');
                    },
                    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
                        alert('1: failed');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>
        Calling Web Services with jQuery/AJAX
    </h3>
    Enter your name:
    <input id="txtName" type="text" />
    <input id="btnCallWebService" value="Call web service" type="button" />
    <div id="response" />
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that is what you want to achieve.
Note I removed `elementName` and I added the full xml request into the data attribute.